# JavaScript setInterval Function Alternative

Tags: javascript

I just developed an JS game which has too many setIntervals to function calls. The intervals are creating the flicker effect which is not acceptable. I wanted to check with experts if can I anyhow make it smooth adopting alternative to setInterval calls which are smooth too?

Have a look at the game http://umairashraf.net23.net/booble/

Comment: Can you show some of the problem code?

Comment: Yup, my cpu got into overdrive with it ... but I don't see much recursion in your code?

Comment: You can always re-write recursive code iteratively using an explicit stack, but are you sure that the recursion is causing the problem?

Comment: Every bubble when created is static, it's being moved to the top via a function call animateBubble(bubble). this function calls itself again and again until the bubble had top less than -50

Comment: `animateBubble` executes repeatedly using `setInterval`. It is not recursive. What you want is a smoother way to do the animation.

Comment: oh yes. just forgot. I replace it with setInterval because it's some smooth now.

Comment: what options do I have for animation in JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no "recursive calls". You have a lot of timers being created. For each new bubble you create a new timer! A hundred of callback functions are being fired every 20 ms! And within each of these calls you do

```
$(bubble).offset().top;
    if (pos >= 0 - $(bubble).height()) {
        $(bubble).css({ top: (pos - 1000) + "px" });
    }
```

A jquery object is constructed (3 times!), its offset is calculated, its height is queried... A hundred of times, every 20 ms!

For each created bubble you should cache its jquery object and its current position. Keep them in arrays or hashes: bubbleJqueryObjects and bubblePositions. Make **a single** animateBubbles() callback, which will **just** update "top" css property of **all** existing bubbles at once. Save 5000 function calls, 15000 jquery object constructions and 5000 position\size queries. Every second.

Comment: You know what is amazing? That it works at all doing it this inefficiently. That is a testament to how far JavaScript engines have come.

Comment: Can you also tell me one more thing. I have defined css rule for bubble -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;. When I remove this rule, the bubbles aren't being shown and their x, y positions both are changed

Comment: JavaScript in modern browsers is being compiled into native code. But THAT animation is too heavy even for superfast JS. Interval is set to 20ms, if bubbles make 50 steps per second they should FLY LIKE HELL, but they're calm and gracefully slow, burning the CPU...

Comment: If you're using webkit-transition, cut your animateBubble() function out completely. Tell the browser once that you want a bubble to be moved from bottom to top in N seconds. And do nothing more, it will move by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into the [Composite design pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#compositepatternjquery).  Its a popular design pattern for handling hierarchical type data and being able to query it in a fast way.

Comment: Sorry that link isnt that good of an example. But if you look up Composite Design Pattern you should find a good example with more code.  There are probably some good examples in Java

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your performance problem is that for every bubble, you create a new animator function that executes every 20ms. That is a lot of functions executing frequently.

You could improve performance by keeping all the bubbles in one data structure, and using one function, executing every 20ms, to update all of them at once.